# Como alterar estilo de irmãos superiores?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Eu tenho um elemento pai (div#workarea) que possui quatro filhos: `figure#start`, `p#first`, `figure#start2` e `p#second`:

```
<div id="workarea">
    <h1 id="title">Área de Testes</h1>
    <figure id="start">
        <img id="gear2" src="img/gear.png">
    </figure>
    <p id="first"></p>
    <figure id="start2">
        <img id="gear3" src="img/gear.png">
    </figure>
    <p id="second"></p>
</div>
```

Gostaria de fazer com que ao setar hover no terceiro filho (`figure#start2`), o primeiro filho (`figure#start`) adquirisse um `transform:rotate(Xdeg)`.

Como isso seria possível?

Vou aplicar o estilo **[neste exemplo](http://learnprogramming.net84.net/testarea.html)**, onde o `figure#start` é a primeira engrenagem e o `figure#start2` é a segunda engrenagem. E seus irmãos sequenciais (`p#first` e `p#second`) correspondem às barrinhas que adquirem um `translateX`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é possível fazer por CSS. Os seletores de irmãos `+` e  `~` só permitem selecionar elementos posteriores no DOM. Por exemplo, é possível selecionar a segunda engrenagem no hover da primeira com [`#start:hover ~ figure`](http://jsfiddle.net/KZBsc/), mas o contrário o CSS não deixa. Você precisa usar JavaScript.

Comment: Foi o que imaginei! Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer o seguinte código:

```
figure#start2:hover #start {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(80deg); /* Compatibilidade com o Google Chrome e Safari */
   -khtml-transform: rotate(80deg); /* Compatibilidade com todos os outros navegadores */
     -moz-transform: rotate(80deg); /* Compatibilidade com o Mozilla Firefox */
       -o-transform: rotate(80deg); /* Compatibilidade com o Opera */
          transform: rotate(80deg); /* Declarando a propriedade CSS */
}
```

Comment: Isso só funcionaria se `#start` fosse *filho* da outra figure, não irmão.